# How to Connect to "imap.gmail.com" using C# within a corporate network having proxy influence

Tags: c#, email, proxy, gmail

I'm not able to connect to imap.gmail.com using either Imap4Client class or  ImapClient class. When I try the Connect method, I'm getting an error as

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

I tried with

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy usesystemdefault="False"/>
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

My code is given below

```
client = new Imap4Client();
try
{
    client.ConnectSsl("imap.gmail.com", 993);
}
    catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    //Getting Exception
}
```

OR

```
using (var client = new ImapClient())
{
    try
    {
        client.Connect("imap.gmail.com", 993, true);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        //Getting the same error here also
    }
}
```

I need any of these codes to connect to the Gmail server in order to read emails. is there any way to avoid this issue?

Comment: The error message indicates you cannot connect to the server.  That are hundreds of reasons for this error message.  The reason falls into 4 types of failures 1) There is no route to the server (or server isn't listening) 2) The port 993 is being blocked 3) Port 993 is TLS/SSL which is a secure connection mode and is failing a security check. 4) The GMAIL account is rejecting the connection.  The FROM address and Login have to be from same account.  Or the credentials are wrong.  I'm not sure why you are using port 993 with gmail which normally uses port 587.Check GMAIL webpage for more info.

Comment: As it is Gmail, there is no chance to miss a route. Also, I'm using an SSL connection. It is clear that my account is not rejecting the connection, because after getting connected only I can authenticate my credentials. So the only reason I can see that is port 993 is being blocked. I have used port 587 also, but still the same error. As I'm trying this from my office network, I have no access to proxy settings. That's why I'm asking whether is there any solution in order to bypass proxy settings.

Comment: No way to unblock proxy server.  You are probably on a Corporate with a firewall that is blocking the port number.  You have Outlook on your network and to make sure the email cannot be hacked all port 587 is forwarded through a proxy server.  There is also a firewall to the internet that is blocking port 587 and the only way of getting through firewall is using port forwarding which you cannot do.  The code will probably work from your home.